# How to query a different index on a runtime field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading how to use runtime fields and follow this instruction: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-search-request.html

The example it gives as below is that it create a runtime field has `day_of_week` name. My question is how I can do an another query inside the `source` field for the runtime field. In other words, the value of the `day_of_week` is saved in another index. Is it possible to do that?

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "day_of_week": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['@timestamp'].value.dayOfWeekEnum.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ROOT))"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "day_of_week": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "day_of_week"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do cross-index access in script.

Comment: Does it work if I preload the mapping and put them inside script. I am not sure about the limtation in the script. Like the maximum size of data I can put

Comment: Not sure If I understand;  The limitation in place is that script does not have access beyond the index its executed on ...

Comment: I mean whether I can preload the mapping data and save it in a variable. Then use this variable in the script?

Comment: Not that im aware of ( mapping is sort of like db schema)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at similar solutions at the moment. Two things I found might meet your needs:

### Enrich processor

> You can use the enrich processor to add data from your existing indices to incoming documents during ingest.
> For example, you can use the enrich processor to:
>
> - Identify web services or vendors based on known IP addresses
> - Add product information to retail orders based on product IDs
> - Supplement contact information based on an email address
> - Add postal codes based on user coordinates

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html

### Lookup Runtime Fields

> Lookup runtime fields can be used to enrich data during the query phase by fetching fields from related indices at the same time. In this way, you can easily enrich data that changes frequently and make informed decisions regarding when to update your primary index with additional data.

https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/search-apis/lookup-runtime-fields/